# why buttons not arranged like page items in a region in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created a set of buttons in oracle apex region but when I run the application its not arranged like the page items

why its not arranged and how I will arrange it to be one by one and space between buttons same space can you see the image please :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options for buttons, pick which one suits you best.

- To behave like a page item, pick the "Position: Region Body". Then you'll have all the options you have with a page item

[image]

- However, each region has a number of pre-defined positions where you can put buttons too. There are less options for configuration in those other pre-defined positions.
- Typically, for a large number of buttons like in your case, I'd use a region template of type "Buttons Container" and then set all button attributes to "Start New Row: No" and "New Column: No". This gives a layout like this:

[image]

**--Update--**

To edit button spacing, use the "template options" for the component template. In the screenshot below: navigate to button > Appearance > Template Options:

[image]

Edit template options:

[image]

Do this for each button. Usually the region template will have similar options, those can also be used.

Comment: thank you so much its working but can you see the second image in question second row buttons need to make space between rows how can I do the space :)

Comment: There are 2 places where this can be set: (1) In the template options of the region (margin left/right) or (2) in the template options of each individual button(margin left/right)

Comment: I tried margin-left:30px and margin-top:30px in button CSS classes but not working can you give example please

Comment: thank you so much i changed spacing top and spacing bottom to Large and its working